# insertSheet advanced options

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I'm looking for a way to add a colour to a newly created sheet within a spreadsheet by a google-apps-script application.

In the documentation, I see that there is a `options` parameter provided in the `insertSheet` [section](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet#insertsheetoptions). But I haven't found any documentation about it and there are no examples.

Where can I find a documentation to these options?

Answer (score 3):

The documentation regarding the options parameter can be found just some few lines below [in the same section you mentioned](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet#insertsheetoptions) under "Advanced parameters".

It may seem confusing at first as the only possible parameter is "template".

[image: insertSheet documentation]

Comment: This seems like the right answer.

Answer (score 2):

I can't answer your question re. the documentation for the options but I would normally do this

```
function copySheet(){
 var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
 var templateSheet = ss.getSheetByName('Sheet1');
 ss.insertSheet('New Sheet',{template: templateSheet)}.setTabColor('RED');
}
```

to set the tab colour and rename the sheet.

Comment: Yes, that's about what I've ended up with. I'm still interested in those mysterious "advanced options" just for the sake of knowing ^^

Comment: I've updated my code above a little bit. I've also had the same problem with the classroom API before, either there is only one 'options' or it's on the 'to-do list' on someone's desk at Google to add some more options!!

Comment: The last line:
ss.insertSheet('New Sheet',{template: templateSheet)}.setTabColor('RED');
should be:
ss.insertSheet('New Sheet',{template: templateSheet}).setTabColor('RED');  The )} before .setTabColor should be })